# Gradle try to find errors in dependencies code

Tags: gradle

I try to migrate to gradle my project, project - addon for webapp, so I need to import dozen of libs of this webapp for development. Some jars contains collisions: same package, same class name, different class content. Important thing - I don't use this classes explicitly in my project.

So, I have config now.

```
...
def LIB_DIR = 'E:\\work\\source\\lib\\'
def wnc101M040 = fileTree(dir: LIB_DIR + 'Windchill-10.1.M040/srclib', include: '**/*.jar')
...

dependencies {
    compile(wnc101M040) {transitive = false}
    ...
}
```

And when i try to compile code. Gradle trows me errors:

```
com\ptc\cat\gxt\client\widget\TabPanelWidget.java(com\ptc\cat\gxt\client\widget:TabPanelWidget.java):112: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method hasBeenSelected()
location: class com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.TabItem
            if(!((TabItem) item).hasBeenSelected()) {
                                ^
com\ptc\cat\gxt\client\widget\TabPanelWidget.java(com\ptc\cat\gxt\client\widget:TabPanelWidget.java):113: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setHasBeenSelected(boolean)
location: class com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.TabItem
                ((TabItem)item).setHasBeenSelected(true);
                               ^
com\ptc\cat\gxt\client\widget\TabPanelWidget.java(com\ptc\cat\gxt\client\widget:TabPanelWidget.java):164: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method blockComponent(com.ptc.cat.gxt.client.widget.TabPanelWidget)
location: class com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.util.Util
            Util.blockComponent(this);
                ^
```

So, why gradle check classes inside my external libs? How to disable this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying that `TabPanelWidget` is external code? `transitive = false` has no effect for file dependencies.

Comment: Yep. Some library jars contains compiled classes, some have sources. All my classes in other package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, javac does try to compile sources in Jars. To prevent this, you'll have to set the right compiler option. If I remember correctly, it is:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs = ["-sourcepath", ""]
}
```

Alternatively, `["-implicit:none"]` might also work.

Comment: Sorry, but this has no effect.

Comment: Actually it's `options.compilerArgs`. You should have gotten a warning that `compilerArgs` doesn't exist.